# Error when calling Prepared Statement, PHP + SQL

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement

I'm attempting to call a prepared statement and retrieve required data. The prepared statement has been created by another developer and their instructions were:

```
declare @DeliveryC nvarchar(15), @DeliveryS  float,  @ErrMsg varchar 

EXECUTE my_prepared_statement @CustNum = 'XX', @PostCode = '2222', @Suburb = 'XX' 
,       @DeliveryCode = @DeliveryC output, @DeliverySurcharge = @DeliveryS output, @ErrMsg = @ErrMsg output
```

I keep getting this error:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 201
>   [code] => 201 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]Procedure or function 'my_prepared_statement' expects parameter
>   '@DeliverySurcharge', which was not supplied.

My PHP code looks like this:

```
    $serverName = "XX"; 
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"XX", "UID"=>"XX", "PWD"=>"XX");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);


    if($conn) {
        echo "Connection established";

        $sql = "{call my_prepared_statement( ?, ?, ? )}";

        $custNum = "XX";  
        $postcode = "2222";  
        $suburbname = "XX";  
        $dcode = "dcode";  
        $dsur = 0.0;  
        $emsg = "error";  
        $params = array(   
            array($custNum, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),  
            array($postcode, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),  
            array($suburbname, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),  
            array(&$dcode, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT), 
            array(&$dsur, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT), 
            array(&$emsg, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT) 
        ); 

        $stmt3 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);

        if( $stmt3 === false )  
        {  
            echo "<br/>Error in executing statement 3.<br/>";  
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); 
        }

        echo "surcharge: " . $dsur . "  ---  code: " . $dcode; 
    }
    else {
        echo "Connection could not be established";
    }

The developer who created the prepared statement has sent me through this information:

    declare @DeliveryC nvarchar(15), @DeliveryS  float,  @ErrMsg varchar 

    EXECUTE my_prepared_statement @CustNum = 'XX', @PostCode = '2222', @Suburb = 'XX' 
    ,       @DeliveryCode = @DeliveryC output, @DeliverySurcharge = @DeliveryS output, @ErrMsg = @ErrMsg output
```

I've never really worked with prepared statements like this before so I'm a bit lost. Sorry if I haven't explained this well. Any ideas how to fix the error and get the data?

Comment: Looks like this line `$sql = "{call my_prepared_statement( ?, ?, ? )}";` is missing 3 `?`'s for the output parameters.

Comment: Outstanding! No more error. Thank you.

Comment: Issue now is to retrieve the required data, instead of the default values of "decode" and 0.0. Any ideas?

Comment: Your code looks like it should do that ok.

Comment: Unfortunately this line is just echoing the default values I've specific above it:  echo "surcharge: " . $dsur . "  ---  code: " . $dcode;

Comment: Perhaps that's the correct result for the inputs you supplied? have you tried looking at the `$emsg` variable?

Comment: The $emsg is also just using it's default value. Perhaps you are right, I'll double check with the other developer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Nick, you're spot on! Everything works well. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries glad to help.